# Can we have other RSS feeds - the current one messes up outlook

Tags: feature-request, feed

I use Newsgator integrated with Outlook 2007 to read my newsfeeds. This works well for the 70 or so feeds I monitor. When I used it with the only feed I could find for serverfault I found that it kept on pulling down new responses to weeks or months old issues and inserting them into outlook at the appropriate date - where they languished unseen and unwanted.

I had to switch it off due to the over the top number of messages I was receiving. I found was spending too much time deleting questions relating to systems I did not have much experience in.

I'd like to suggest a more sophisticated RSS feed where you can choose things such as
- Only pull X responses
- Only unanswered questions
- Which tags to ignore or include
- Choose to see answers and/or responses
- Separate options for threads I have posed or participated in

A simple page  (ha ha, aren't they all simple until you have to write them) which allowed the user to select various options to enable or disable could construct a feed url. This url could use the above options as parameters, allowing more people to watch for interesting questions and to jump in and answer them.

Answer (score 2):

Are you aware that you can combine tags using AND and OR?

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/10/tags-and-tags-or-tags/

and of course each of these has a RSS feed.

Comment: This needs a not specifier. It works for selecting tags on stuff you know about but will exclude new tags and forces you to specify a huge list of the things you could possibly answer. Its no big deal to see some traffic which you cannot answer but it would be good to cut it down. I'm not sure if there is a practical way of doing this with a url, maybe the possible combinations are too much. The effect is that at the moment I don't monitor stackoverflow because its too busy.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a flexible application that converts API requests into RSS feeds:

[http://quickmediasolutions.com/stack2rss/logo.png](https://stackapps.com/questions/1599/stack2rss-a-json-to-rss-conversion-service)

An example feed that displays all questions tagged `'wxwidgets'` on StackOverflow:

> http://quickmediasolutions.com/stack2rss/stackoverflow/questions?tagged=wxwidgets&body=true

It is very flexible and can limit the data supplied as you mention in your question.

For example:

- to limit the number of results returned in the feed, add `pagesize=`**`XXX`** to the URL where **XXX** represents the number of questions you want on each feed.
- To only have the feed return unanswered questions, use the following query:

  > http://quickmediasolutions.com/stack2rss/stackoverflow/questions/unanswered?tagged=wxwidgets&body=true